# AngularJs: ngRepeat Increasing by increments other than 1

Tags: c#, angularjs, razor

Is there a way in AngularJs to Increases by increments other than 1 such as the C# Razor example bellow:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i+=3)
{
    <p>Value: listOfObjects[i].value</p>
}
```

Comment: No, you'll have to iterate over an array, e.g. [0, 2, 4]

Comment: good question, don't think you can do this with ngRepeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't directly but you can make a little workaround on this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in listOfObjects">
    <div ng-if="$index % 3 == 0">
       {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to iterate over array collection, and need its current index somewhere. In that case you could use `{{$index`. `ng-repeat` has that built in, `$index` will give you current index of element if its array. You could use `ng-if` with condition `$index%3==0`

**Controller**

```
$scope.listOfObjects = [0, 1, 2, 3];
```

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in listOfObjects" ng-if="$index%3==0">
   {{item}}
</div>
```

Comment: it's not an answer to the question, OP wants to iterate every nth element in ngRepeat not increase index in binding

Comment: @maurycy check update, sorry i missed that part :( thanks for heads up

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use this kind of structure:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in nfg">
  <span ng-if="!($index %= 3)">Some text here, each 3rd loop</span>
</div>
```

I had hoped you could use a filter in the ng-repeat itself, but I couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, ngRepeat doesn't have that facility, you could do it with ngIf but I personally prefer the filters since they are stateless

#### JS

```
.filter('everyNth', function() {
  return function(arrayOfElements, nth) {
    var result = []
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfElements.length; i += nth) {
      result.push(arrayOfElements[i])
    }
    return result
  }
})
```

#### HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | everyNth:3">
```